# Bootstrap Styling with Phoenix's Delete Method

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, phoenix-framework

I have a variety of links that show up in my bootstrap navbar such as logging in, registering, visiting pages, and logging out.  When I use the delete method in the link helper I lose my default bootstrap CSS.  For example the following link helper:

`<li><%= link "Register", to: user_path(@conn, :new) %></li>`

generates the following html:

`<li><a href="/users/new">Register</a></li>`

However if I want the delete method, such as when logging out:

`<li><%= link "Log out", to: session_path(@conn, :delete, @current_user), method: "delete" %></li>`

It generates a form such as:

```
<li><form action="/sessions/3" class="link" method="post">
  <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="delete">
  <input name="_csrf_token" type="hidden" value="QA1vDhw/PhoBcgIwCgJJVCQPJQ4FAAAA/U8oImxsGBgDOF+crLSodA==">
  <a data-submit="parent" href="#" rel="nofollow">Log out</a>
</form></li>
```

Now my anchor tag is within a form and I've lost my default CSS.

I fixed it by using a custom class:

```
.bad-bootstrap-link {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  color: #777;
}
```

Is this the only way to do this? Am I missing something? This is terribly inconvenient that I have to redefine CSS styles for delete links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem and I added a bootstrap css class `navbar-text` as shown below for Bootstrap 3. That's close enough for me.

```
<li><%= link gettext("logout"), to: session_path(@conn, :delete, @current_user), method: "delete", class: "navbar-text" %></li>
```

For Bootstrap 4 I use the classes `nav-item nav-link`:

```
<li><%= link gettext("logout"), to: session_path(@conn, :delete, @current_user), method: "delete", class: "nav-item nav-link" %></li>
```

Comment: Using a bootstrap class is better than my solution, but I'm hoping there might be another way around this issue.  Leaving the question open for now.

Answer (score 0):

You could hide the form, and add another link that submits the form. This is somewhat hacky, but the alternative is to dive into the CSS file or dive into the JS file.

```
<li>
  <%= link "Logout", to: auth_path(@conn, :logout), method: "delete", class: "hidden", id: "logout-form" %>
  <%= link "Logout", to: "#", onclick: "document.getElementById('logout-form').parentNode.submit();return false;" %>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with the following css rule:

```
form[method=post].link {
  display: initial;
}
```

**Before**
[image: before]

**After**
[image: after]